# WebKitBrowser runtime exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dll, runtimeexception

I have a C# application, with a GUI that has been written in XAML.

I have previously had my application in a working state, where the GUI is displayed with three 'tabs'- one that is a web browser (using the `WebKitBrowser`, one that displays some information about the application's connection status with various servers, and another that allows users to upload files to a server.

I recently tried to make some changes to my application: I had written a completely separate C# application (again, using XAML for the GUI) that would allow users to view PDF files from within the application. This Document Viewer application was fully functioning- users could browse to the location of a document using File->Open, and when they 'opened' the PDF, a 'preview' of it would be displayed inside the application. I did this using the `WebKitBrowser` to display the document- browsing to the location opened by the user.

Having got the 'Document Reader' up and running and fully functioning as a standalone application, I then tried to incorporate it into my original application: I did this by adding the XAML markup for a new 'tab' inside my application, copying the XAML from the Document Reader into the tags for the new tab, and adding the C# code to the code-behind file.

However, after doing this, I kept getting a runtime error, which I couldn't seem to resolve, so I reverted the changes I had made to my application back to the working state I had prior to trying to add the Document Reader to it (i.e. it does not currently have any code/ markup for the Document Reader). But I now find that when trying to run my application again, I am still getting the same runtime error I was getting after adding the Document Reader to my application.

The runtime error presents itself as a `XamlParseException`, and when I 'View Detail' on it, the 'InnerException' states: `{"Failed to initialize activation context"}`.

The 'InnerException' inside that states `null`, and the 'Source' is `WebKitBrowser`.

The Stack Trace is:

```
at WebKit.ActivationContext.Initialize() at WebKit.WebKitBrowser..ctor() at Agent.MainWindow..ctor() in C:\Users\...\MainWindow.xaml.cs: line 37
```

Line 37 is the global variable declaration of the `WebKitBrowser` in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
WebKit.WebKitBrowser browser = new WebKit.WebKitBrowser();
```

As I mentioned, this was the code that I had when my application was last in a perfectly working state, so I don't understand why I'm now getting this exception...

Any help/ advice anyone can give with regard to how to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: If I comment out the declaration of the instance of the `WebKitbrowser`, and all of its uses in my code, then my application runs again, so it would seem that the issues I am having are something to do with the `WebKitBrowser`... anyone have any ideas what I could do to resolve them?